# Не устанавливается npm, и не показывает ошибок

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Я скачал nodejs. Зашел в nodejs command prompt. Написал node -v, оно показало версию. Далее я попробовал установить npm, но он не установился и не показало никаких ошибок. После этого, я попробовал создать react приложение через npx create-react-app nameapp, но так же как и в прошлый раз, не показало никаких ошибок и react приложение не создалось.

[image: установка]

[image: создание приложения]

Comment: `npm -v` что показывает?

Comment: Ничего. Просто три пустых строки

Comment: перезагрузка не помогла?

Comment: нет, не помогла. Переустанавливал пару раз nodejs, перезагружал компьютер, не помогло

Comment: Попорбуй заново установить ноду. И ещё глянь, что в папке с глобальными пакетами лежит. И вообщк `where npm` что говорит?